# custom fields type "Select Date" are broken as of 4.7

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, profile

I was wondering if someone else has encountered this issue and if there is resolution: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18379

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I did, and I posted a fix to that issue. You can find it under the "links" section.

Comment: cheers @Coleman, I've written a comment in Jira.